# JavaScript modify Number object (wrapper) in place - downcasting

Tags: javascript, object, numbers

The question is about built-in [Number object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) (a primitive wrapper).

```
var n = new Number(2);
console.log(n); // Number {}
console.log(typeof n); // "object"

n++;
console.log(n); // 3
console.log(typeof n); // "number"
```

I can see that JS is making an implicit typecast here. Precisely, downcasting `Number` object to `number` primitive. Is there any way to modify Number object in place without such downcasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Number` instances are immutable. You'd have to do:

```
n = new Number(++n);
```

to get a new instance one bigger than a prior instance.

Comment: Thanks for precise answer. What is the usage of such objects then?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz mostly they provide an object from which the methods on the Number prototype can be called. At least, that's all I can think of. Number is not as interesting as String in that regard.